# затрагиваемый vs затронутый

Tags: грамматика

In the following, is **затрагиваемые** interchangeable with **затронутыe**?

> дети, **затрагиваемые** вооруженными конфликтами

Answer (score 2):

Neither is a good choice for this particular case.  I would say: "дети, пострадавшие/страдающие в результате вооруженных конфликтов".

"Затронуть" and "затрагивать" are pretty much the same word and both mean the same: "to touch" someone's emotions or feelings, or heart.

However, assuming someone has (incorrectly) used the word "затрагиваемые/затронутые" in this case, the difference is:

"затронутые" -- "some children *have been* affected by" in any physical, psychological or financial way. They might be implying some knowledge of such children.

"затрагиваемые" -- the "children *are being* affected or *are being* exposed to a great chance of being affected in any possible way. So, here they are most likely talking in general. Here, they would be implying a well known fact that children do get affected by war.

Comment: wrong the both parts of this answer